# Perform an automated transaction using 1inch API

Tags: solidity, transactions, python, external-api

To perform an automated 1 inch transaction I use these two functions.
It works well at first. Unfortunately, in the last few days I have always had the same errors:

- Fail with error 'Return amount is not enough'
- Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]

  ```
  def get_api_call_data(_from_coin,_to_coin):
      global api_data

      try:

        call_data = requests.get(
        f'https://api.1inch.exchange/v1.1/swap?fromTokenSymbol={_from_coin}&toTokenSymbol={_to_coin}&amount={_amount_to_exchange}&fromAddress={base_account}&slippage={slippage}&disableEstimate=true')

        api_data = call_data.json()

      except:
        logging.exception("get_api_call_data")

      return api_data


  def one_inch_token_swap(_from_coin,_to_coin):
    global tx_hash

    web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(eth_provider_url))
    nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(base_account)
    json_data = get_api_call_data(_from_coin,_to_coin)
    data = json_data['data']
    to = json_data['to']
    value = _amount_to_exchange


    url_fees = 'https://ethgasstation.info/api/ethgasAPI.json?'
    r_fees = requests.get(url_fees)
    js_fees = json.loads(r_fees.content)
    Fastest = js_fees['fastest']

    tx = {
        'nonce': nonce,
        'to': to,  
        'value': _amount_to_exchange,         
        'gasPrice':(Fastest+100)*(100000000),
        'from': base_account,
        'data': data,
    }

    gas = web3.eth.estimateGas(tx)
    tx["gas"] = gas

    signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, private_key)
    tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
  ```

what could be the cause of this error?

Comment: it seems to be due to the slippage percent... on some token the minimum slippage is very high, i got this error some times...
but i'm interested to do the same script with the 1inch api on BSC, i'm a beginner with web3, could you give me some clue about it ? thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Did you "approve" _from_coin to the 1inch address?

1inch can not swap your token if you do not approve your tokens for him.

Comment: Yes I unlock the token directly on the 1inch site. Could this be related to eth_provider_url?

Comment: how much is your slippage? your exchange result might be less than the minReturn due to slipage size.

Comment: I set the slippage to 5%. Is it possible to add a min return inside data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from oneinch Swap API call You get a json object were (apart the transaction constructor, tx), there are two fields called

```
"toTokenAmount"   : "1089293791578517848"
"fromTokenAmount" : "10000000000000000"
```

from were You an do your last test before signing and sending the tx. In example You can check

```
toTokenAmount - (toTokenAmount * ({slippage} / 100)) > minimum_desired_amount
```